# The signer's certificate is not valid for signing

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-debugging

While debugging in Visual Studio I am getting this error

> The signer's certificate is not valid for signing,  An error occured
>   while attempting to sign:sharepoint_link.dll,The command
>   ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\SPLink2010\SharePoint_Link\ITOPIA_certificate2.p12"/p
>   $h0pp1ng /t "http://tsa.starfieldtech.com" "SharePoint_Link.dll""
>   exited with code 1

I have created a new test certificate and imported it through certificate import wizard but I'm still getting this error. I also have removed the old temporary certificate using `certmgr.exe` but in vain, I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 39):

It's simple; just follow the following steps:

1. **Right click on Project** in Solution Explorer on right side panel, and choose **Properties** from the context menu. *Remember to right click on Main Project, not solution*.
2. A window will open, then click on **Signing** tab.
3. There you can see a button **Create Test Certificate**, click on it and it will ask for password just leave it empty and there you are done.

Comment: Does anyone know what the process is for this in Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: you have to right click your project and hit publish, then follow through the clickonce settings there